# Citrix: Why is the XASession.ClientAddress Null?

Tags: c#, sdk, citrix, xenapp

```
using Citrix.Common.Sdk;
using Citrix.XenApp.Sdk;
using Citrix.XenApp.Commands;
using Citrix.Management.Automation;
```

I am trying to place the client address into an array to add to a list. The problem is the ClientAddress keeps coming back null when I test it. I can see the user online and their client address is visible in App Center. It has no problem coming back with the ServerName. Anybody know why ClientAddress doesn't work?

```
    private List<string[]> findUser(string strUser)
    {

        List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

        GetXASessionByFarm sessions = new GetXASessionByFarm(true);

        foreach (XASession session in CitrixRunspaceFactory.DefaultRunspace.ExecuteCommand(sessions))
        {
            if (session.AccountName == objWINS + "\\" + strUser)
            {
                string[] result = new string[3];
                result[0] = strUser;
                result[1] = session.ServerName; //This is working, it comes back with the server name.
                result[2] = session.ClientAddress; //This isn't working, it comes back blank.
                MessageBox.Show(result[2]);
                list.Add(result);
            }

        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question was to add the following line after GetXASessionByFarm is declared:

```
sessions.Full = true;
```

For example:

```
private List<string[]> findUser(string strUser)
{

    List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

    GetXASessionByFarm sessions = new GetXASessionByFarm(true);

    sessions.Full = true;

    foreach (XASession session in CitrixRunspaceFactory.DefaultRunspace.ExecuteCommand(sessions))
    {
        if (session.AccountName == objWINS + "\\" + strUser)
        {
            string[] result = new string[3];
            result[0] = strUser;
            result[1] = session.ServerName; //This is working, it comes back with the server name.
            result[2] = session.ClientAddress; //This isn't working, it comes back blank.
            MessageBox.Show(result[2]);
            list.Add(result);
        }

    }
    return list;
}
```

The reason for this is because the command by default does not return the full amount of information. I had to translate this and do some guesswork based on the Get-XASessions powershell command. It's always a good feeling when I figure things out by myself. Apparently I'm on the edge of the wild west frontier in this area of software development. Nobody is doing this.

Comment: is there any credentials here? or I can just use this code straight up, and is the code run on the server or remotely connect to it like webservice? thank you